# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `store` is marked as required in `Provider`, but its value is `undefined`. in Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

How to resolve this error in react-redux project
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhAHc.png)
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `store` is marked as required in `Provider`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Provider

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import SignUp from './Components/SignUp'
import SignIn from './Components/SignIn'
import Home from './Components/Home'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {firebaseApp} from './Database/firebaseApp'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {store} from './Store/Store'
import {logUser} from './Store/Actions'

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory} >

        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} ></Route>
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} ></Route>
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} ></Route>

      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

//store code below

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware,combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from "redux-logger";
//import logger from 'redux-logger'

//import rootReducer from './Reducers/rootReducer'
import {authReducer} from "./Reducers/authReducer"

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authReducer
})
const logger = createLogger();

let store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger) );

export default store;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You export `store` as default: `export default store;`

You need to import it this way: `import store from './Store/Store'`

There are two kinds of export:

- `export myVar` must be imported with `{` and `}`
- `export default myVar` must be imported without `{` and `}`

This is useful to export/import multiple variables/functions from a file:

```
// file.js
export a;
export b;
export default c;

//otherfile.js
import c, { a , b} from './file';
```