# The prop `store.subscribe` is marked as required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to connect a component to the redux store, but am receiving:

`Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'store.subscribe' is marked as required in`Connect(StoreLocation)`, but its value is 'undefined'.`

I have been using redux with this project for awhile now without issue, but this component is erroring out for some reason and I'm clueless as to why at this point :(

The store populates a collection of stores (brick and mortar locations with addresses, phone numbers, etc used for shipping selections) within `DeliverySection.js`.

Then each `StoreLocation.js` component will allow the user to view it's info, select it, etc.  It's bare bones right now as I am seeing the error even at this basic point.  If I switch the `export default connect()(StoreLocation)` statement with `export default StoreLocation` it works without issue.

Any ideas?

**DeliverySection.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// Components
import Loader from '../../utils/Loader'
import StoreLocation from './StoreLocation'

// Stote
import { getAllStores } from '../../../store/actions/storeLocation'
import { REACT_APP_SITE_KEY } from '../../../shared/vars'

// CSS
import '../../../css/delivery.css'

class DeliverySection extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getAllStores(REACT_APP_SITE_KEY);
    }

    render() {
        const { stores, isLoading } = this.props

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="delivery-heading">
                    <h2>Choose a store near you:</h2>
                    <button className="btn btn--red btn--heading" name="ship-to-address">Ship To An Address</button>
                </div>

                <div>
                    {isLoading ? (
                        <Loader />
                    ) : (
                        !isLoading && !!stores ? (
                            stores.map((store, i) => <StoreLocation key={i} store={store} />)
                        ) : (
                            <div>
                                There are no store locations to deliver to.<br />
                                Ship to an address!
                            </div>
                        )
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        stores: state.storeLocation.stores,
        isLoading: state.storeLocation.isLoading
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllStores })(DeliverySection)
```

**StoreLocation.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { setDelivery } from '../../../store/actions/checkout'

class StoreLocation extends Component {
    render() {
        const { store } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="store-location">
                <div className="store-row">
                    <div className="store-col"><div className="store-title">{store.title}</div></div>
                    <div className="store-col">
                        {store.address}
                        {store.formatted_location &&
                            <div>{store.formatted_location}</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="store-col">
                        <button className="btn select-store" onClick={() => this.props.setDelivery(store)}>Ship to this store<span className="icon-checkmark"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="store-row">
                    <div className="store-col">
                        <div className="ajax-message" data-hbs-id="postal-{id}"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" id={`postal-${store.id}`} value={store.postal} />
                        <div className="see-map"><span className="icon-location"></span>See on map</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="store-col">{store.description}</div>
                    <div className="store-col"></div>
                </div>
                {store.phone &&
                    <div className="store-row">
                        <div className="store-col"></div>
                        <div className="store-col">{store.phone}</div>
                        <div className="store-col"></div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, { setDelivery })(StoreLocation)
// export default StoreLocation
```

Comment: You are missing a param for the connect function, it is a function that receives the state and returns an object to pass it as props to your component, it’s usually called mapStateToProps

Comment: @Jalissa The parameters for the connect function are optional. Please check https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-just-dispatch-and-dont-listen-to-store

Comment: My mistake, you are right @palsrealm ! Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because you are using store as your prop name.  You are overwriting the prop react-redux passes through the HOC.  Since, the object you pass for store does not have a subscribe method, you get this error.

If you change the name of your prop, you'll be in good shape again.

Comment: Yes!!  So obvious now haha  Thanks for answering this so long after I asked it :)

Answer (score 2):

After doing a quick Google I came across this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253644/warning-failed-prop-type-the-prop-store-is-marked-as-required-in-provider/43253753).
That problem, which is similar to yours, was based on the way the store was exported. Have a look at that and see if gets you going in the right direction. I can't comment without seeing your store export code.

On a personal preference note I would use something other than 'store' as the variable for each instance in your map of stores. Since you are using Redux it could get semantically confusing whether you are referring to the Redux store or an instance of a store object.

I think it's fine that you are having StoreLocation handle the setting of delivery. I'm a big fan of breaking things down into smaller components.

Finally, just because I happen to notice it, you have a misspelling in DeliverySection. Line 8 reads `//Stote`. I'm guessing you meant `//Store`.

Comment: You can invoke `connect()` without parameters if you only want to inject `dispatch` into your props. Please check https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-just-dispatch-and-dont-listen-to-store

Comment: Sorry @palsrealm, I misread that in the docs and just updated my comment.

Comment: I've edited the question with my intentions with the redux store.  I figured that the StoreLocation component should handle the setting of the selected delivery item on it's own rather than the parent component.  Maybe I'm incorrect.

Comment: @Gurnzbot I've updated my comment based on your edits to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance as I think this should go under the comment section, but the code you pasted looks alright. You say disconnecting the StoreLocation component fixes things. Is there a reason you want to connect that component? You're not mapping any state to props or using dispatch in that component.

Otherwise, make sure that you're correctly initializing the store with the reducers you need and check that the modules you're using are imported properly - especially the ones you are passing to the connect function (getAllStores).

Comment: I planned on using a dispatch function called `setDelivery` that will set the StoreLocation as the active item, but I decided to remove anything I could from the issue to get it as bare-bones as I could.  `getAllStores` does populate as expected if I change the last line to `export default StoreLocation`.  I'm at a loss as to why connecting the StoreLocation component is throwing errors.