# React-redux error "The prop `store` is marked as required in `Root`, but its value is `undefined"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use react + redux and currently get the following error messages:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `store` is marked as required in `Root`, but its value is `undefined`. 
in Root (at index.js:11)

index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `store` is marked as required in `Provider`, but its value is `undefined`. 
in Provider (at Root.js:8)
in Root (at index.js:11)

index.js:2178 Warning: Failed child context type: The child context `store` is marked as required in `Provider`, but its value is `undefined`.
in Provider (at Root.js:8)
in Root (at index.js:11)
```

I have already checked my exports/imports in line with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253644/warning-failed-prop-type-the-prop-store-is-marked-as-required-in-provider), but can't figure out what is going wrong...

My App.js looks as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './redux/rootReducer'
import Home from './pages/Home.js';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
console.log(store.getState());

class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <Provider store={store}>
     <Router>
       <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
       </div>
     </Router>
   </Provider >
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

The console.log shows that the store is not undefined but in its initial state before being past into the Provider. The component that is currently supposed to use this state is the following (some of the logic is still missing):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
  authStatus: state.authStatus
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateAuthStatus: (authStatus) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'UPDATE_AUTHSTATUS',
        status: authStatus
      })
    }
  };
};

class LoginPopover extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
    console.log(authStatusChanged.authStatus);
    }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPopover);
```

My reducer function:

```
import { UPDATE_AUTHSTATUS } from './actions'


const initialState = {
  authStatus: ['unauthenticated'],
}

export const authStatusChanged = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_AUTHSTATUS:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      authStatus: action.status
    });

    default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

and combineReducers

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { authStatusChanged } from './reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authStatusChanged
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Integrated @el-aoutar-hamza 's comment

Comment: This fixed the undefined state coming from the LoginPopover component, however, i still get the same errors in the console. Overall, the application is running and state operations seem to be working.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I am sitting with the same error in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reducer `authStatusChanged` handles only one part of the state which is `authStatusChanged` (or whatever name you pass to `combineReducers`), and since it returns an object (for example `{authStatus: ['unauthenticated']}`) your state will look like this :

```
state = {
    authStatusChanged: {
        authStatus: ['unauthenticated']
    }
}
```

So when you try to access the state in `mapStateToProps`, do it this way : `state.authStatusChanged.authStatus` and not like this `state.authStatus` .

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the undefined state coming from the LoginPopover component, however, i still get the same errors in the console. Overall, the application is running though.